# Choosing from list by index

Tags: c#

I'm asking a question again regarding my "note". With your help I was able to display the names of txt files from the main folder and their indexes from the list. I didn't get far on my own, this time I stood on selecting the file to be displayed. The idea was that I display the indexes and using them, select the file to be displayed (or, in fact, its contents). And I don't know how to do it for anything. I tried it this way, but following this line of thinking I would have to make an infinite case's because txt files can be any number. Here I limited myself to 3 and it works, but how to do it so I don't have to repeat the case with each new note?

```cs
public void EditTxt()
{
    Console.Clear();

    string path = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory);
    var files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).ToList();

    for (var index = 0; index < files.Count; index++)
    {
        var filename = Path.GetFileName(files[index]);
        Console.WriteLine($"[{index}]  {filename}");
    }

    char choice = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;

    Console.WriteLine("\n");

    switch (choice)
    {
        case '1':
            Console.WriteLine(ShowTxt(files[0]));
            break;
        case '2':
            Console.WriteLine(ShowTxt(files[1]));
            break;
        case '3':
            Console.WriteLine(ShowTxt(files[2]));
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("");
            break;
    }

}

public string ShowTxt(string file)
{
    // Displays the content of txt 
    string path = file;
    string content = File.ReadAllText(path, Encoding.UTF8);
    return content;
}
```

Comment: `int.TryParse` then use that to index into your array

Comment: `char` won't be enough if you have >9 files. You also _display_ your index as 0-based but your switch-case is 1-based ... and finally you do not need a switch to begin with. You can `int.TryParse(choice, out int index)` , then check boundaries, then use it as index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `char choice = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;`
do the following:

```
var fileIndex = 0;
bool success = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out fileIndex);
```

and then use `fileIndex` to index your list/array, if `TryParse` returns `true`.

Comment: With `bool success = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int fileIndex);` you can even spare the extra line. Mind to also check the boundaries. As of now, you only know that the user entered _some_ valid integer. It could still be < 0 or >= array.Length.

Comment: That is a bit out of question scope, but you are right. Then Ryan Wilson's solution is more robust from this point of view.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for the hard coding of indexes, you can use the user's selection to grab the file associated with the index since you are storing the files from the directory in an `IEnumerable`, this includes error handling:

```
//replace with ReadLine so the user can input a number larger than 9
string choice = Console.ReadLine();
int fileindex = -1;

if(!Int.TryParse(choice, out fileindex)
   //Not an integer, throw an error

if(fileindex < 1 || fileindex > files.Count)
  //Index out of range error

//Show file based on (fileindex - 1), we are using (fileindex - 1) as
//you are displaying file at zero index as file 1
Console.WriteLine(ShowTxt(files[fileindex - 1]));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static void EditTxt()
    {
        int idx;

        Console.Clear();

        string path = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory);
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).ToList();

        for (var index = 0; index < files.Count; index++)
        {
            var filename = Path.GetFileName(files[index]);
            Console.WriteLine($"[{index}]  {filename}");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Enter an index from the list above and press the Enter key:");
        string choice = Console.ReadLine();
        
        Console.WriteLine("\n");

        if(int.TryParse(choice, out idx) && idx >= 0 && idx < files.Count)
            Console.WriteLine(ShowTxt(files[idx]));
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid selection!");
    }

    public static string ShowTxt(string file)
    {
        // Displays the content of txt 
        string path = file;
        string content = File.ReadAllText(path, Encoding.UTF8);
        return content;
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```cs
public void EditTxt()
{
    Console.Clear();

    string path = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory);
    var files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).ToList();

    for (var index = 0; index < files.Count; index++)
    {
        var filename = Path.GetFileName(files[index]);
        Console.WriteLine($"[{index}]  {filename}");
    }
    int choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadKey().KeyChar.ToString());

    Console.WriteLine("\n");

    Console.WriteLine(ShowTxt(files[Convert.ToInt32(choice.ToString())+1]));
}

public string ShowTxt(string file)
{
    // Displays the content of txt 
    string path = file;
    string content = File.ReadAllText(path, Encoding.UTF8);
    return content;
}
```

Comment: And how to get file with index 10?

Comment: you have to remove the char and change the type to an int

Comment: This will throw an exception if the conversion fails. TryParse is much more straightforward

Comment: I Changed the answer now it should work

Comment: You'll have an "off-by-one" user experience :(